# Variables from player class won't work in enemy class

Tags: python, pygame

I made 2 classes : 1 Player class and 1 Enemy class. I want that the enemy follows the player around.
To do that I need to get the current player position from the Player class and use it in the Enemy class.
But that isn't workink, and I don't know what to do

This is the code by now:

```
class Player():
    
    def __init__(self,xPlayer,yPlayer):
        self.xPlayer = xPlayer
        self.yPlayer = yPlayer
    
    def display(self):
        playerRect = pygame.Rect(self.xPlayer,self.yPlayer,25,25)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,255),playerRect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.xPlayer = self.xPlayer + velPlayer
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.xPlayer = self.xPlayer - velPlayer
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.yPlayer = self.yPlayer + velPlayer
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.yPlayer = self.yPlayer - velPlayer

player1 = Player(100,100)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self,xEnemy,yEnemy):
        self.xEnemy = xEnemy
        self.yEnemy = yEnemy
    
    def display(self):
        enemyRect = pygame.Rect(self.xEnemy,self.yEnemy,25,25)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),enemyRect)
    
    def move(self):
        if xPlayer < xEnemy:
            xEnemy = xEnemy - velEnemy
        if xPlayer > xEnemy:
            xEnemy = xEnemy + velEnemy
        if yPlayer < yEnemy:
            yEnemy = yEnemy + velEnemy
        if yPlayer > yEnemy:
            yEnemy = yEnemy - velEnemy

enemy1 = Enemy(200,200)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------


running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    
    ecranAlb()
    player1.move()
    player1.display()
    enemy1.move()
    enemy1.display()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enemy` must not be derived from `Player` class. Pass the instance of the `Player` class to the `move` method of the `Enemy` class:

```py
class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self,xEnemy,yEnemy):
        self.xEnemy = xEnemy
        self.yEnemy = yEnemy
    
    def display(self):
        enemyRect = pygame.Rect(self.xEnemy,self.yEnemy,25,25)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),enemyRect)
    
    def move(self, player):
        if player.xPlayer < self.xEnemy:
            self.xEnemy -= velEnemy
        if player.xPlayer > self.xEnemy:
            self.xEnemy += velEnemy
        if player.yPlayer < self.yEnemy:
            self.yEnemy += velEnemy
        if player.yPlayer > self.yEnemy:
            self.yEnemy -= velEnemy
```

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    ecranAlb()
    player1.move()
    player1.display()
    enemy1.move(player1)  # <--- pass player1
    enemy1.display()
    pygame.display.flip()
```